# Upload Data in SQL database using excel upload functionality in ASP.NET website

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

I want to create excel upload functionality in my website (.net based), where users can upload some data in specific excel format using upload/browse button. This data will get inserted in the back end SQL Database.
 If the data is not in correct forma, it should throw an error message. 
I have done some research but could not find correct solution. Can anyone guide me in this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a nice solution [Here](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Read-and-Import-Excel-Sheet-into-SQL-Server-Database-in-ASP.Net.aspx). It gives me the option to choose which particular sheet i am uploading in an excel book for .xls and .xlsx formats.